# How to connect Model / Data Model

Tags: magento2, model

- `Vendor/ModuleName/Model/TestModel.php`
- `Vendor/ModuleName/Model/Data/TestModel.php`
- `Vendor/ModuleName/Model/TestModelRepository.php`

Interfaces are already created.

The Data Model contains for eg. these methods:

```
public function getFirstname() {};
public function getLastname() {};
```

the regular Model contains:

```
public function getName() {
    return $this->getDataModel()->getFirstname() . ' ' . $this->getDataModel()->getLastname();
}
```

The new Magento service contracts architecture recommend to seperate entity information methods (from data model) and "`action`" methods (regular model). The repository return an instance of data model, so how can i call the *getName()* method from regular model ? Should i create a `new feactory` for the regular model and add the data model data?

<sup>**Magento 2.2.6**</sup>

Maybe someone has a good example for me?

lots of thanks

Answer (score 0):

Model in custom Magento module need 3 files:

- `Model`
- `Resource Model`
- `Resource Model Collection`

About the `Factory Object` you don't need to create it, Magento do it automatically.

in Magento, the `Factory` class is composed in : **name of Model class** + "**Factory**" word.

**Exemple** : model class name is : `Vendor\Module\Model\Test`, the Factory class will be : `Vendor\Module\Model\TestFactory`

When Magento find a class name that ends in the "`Factory`" word, it automatically generate this Factory class in the `var/generation`.

Comment: thanks, that's clear and wasn't my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question,

But I guess a way to do this would be :

```
if ($customer && $customer->getId()) {
    $modelCustomer = $this->customerFactory->create();
    $modelCustomer->updateData($customer);
}
```

With $customer being your data model and $modelCustomer being your real model.